# Filtering out JSONB array elements containing specific condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, jsonb

I have a table:
"events" with jsonb column "logs".

Having events record with following logs:

```
[
{state: "something", recorded_at: "some-timestamp"},
{state: "other", recorded_at: "some-other-timestamp"},
{nothing: "interesting", recorded_at: "timestamp"}
]
```

I would like to perform this query:

- select record with logs that have filtered out entries without "state" key

I don't really want to construct WHERE query conditions, I just want to filter out "logs" in returned result.

How to do it?

Comment: That 's two questions in one, which does not follow SO guidelines. You should ask just one question.

Answer (score 1):

To get records whose none of `logs` object has key `'state'`, you can use `not exists` and `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
select e.*
from events e
where not exists(select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(e.logs) x(obj) where obj ? 'state')
```

On the other hand, if you are not looking to filter out *records*, but instead want to filter out nested *json objects* that have key `'state'`:

```
select e.*, x.new_logs
from events e
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(x.obj order by x.ord) new_logs
    from jsonb_array_elements(e.obj) with ordinality x(obj, ord)
    where not obj ? 'state'
) x
```

Comment: I couldn't make your exact code to work, but something like this worked for me:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON(events.id) events.id, filtered_logs, filtered_logs->>'recorded_at' AS recorded_at FROM "events" CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(logs) AS filtered_logs WHERE (filtered_logs->>'state' IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "events"."id" DESC, "recorded_at" DESC`

I had to add DISTINCT to return only single row